# Tree diagram - prevent labels overlapping nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've made a collapsible tree diagram in d3 (v5), a simplified version of which can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/philipnye/cwj9nkhr/.

Each node has a label, but labels are only displayed where there is enough space for them not to overlap each other or get too close to the edge of the SVG. In the linked example, on first load labels only appear for the first two depths of the tree diagram.

`requiredSpacing` is used to approximate how much space is needed, while `minSpacing` checks the minimum spacing that exists between nodes at each depth.

The following lines position the nodes and labels, with a transition effect:

```
var nodeUpdate=nodeEnter.merge(node)
    .transition()
    .duration(function() {
        if (loaded==0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return duration;
        }
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return radiuses[d.depth];
    })
    .attr("class", function(d) {
        if (d._children) {
            return "filled";
        } else {
            return "unfilled";
        }
    });

nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
        if (minSpacing[d.depth]<requiredSpacing[d.depth]*2 || (d.data.position=='left' && Math.ceil(d.x/5)*5-radiuses[d.depth]-requiredSpacing[d.depth]<margin.left) || (d.data.position=='right' && Math.ceil(d.x/5)*5+radiuses[d.depth]+requiredSpacing[d.depth]>width)) {
            return 1e-6;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    })
    .attr("class", function(d) {
        if (minSpacing[d.depth]<requiredSpacing[d.depth]*2 || (d.data.position=='left' && Math.ceil(d.x/5)*5-radiuses[d.depth]-requiredSpacing[d.depth]<margin.left) || (d.data.position=='right' && Math.ceil(d.x/5)*5+radiuses[d.depth]+requiredSpacing[d.depth]>width)) {
            return "nodeLabel nonselectable";
        }
        else {
            return "nodeLabel";
        }
    })
```

I set the opacity of labels which there isn't space to show to 1e-6 (to enable a transition) and give them a class of `nonselectable`, which means the labels can't be selected. But I don't actually remove them - and I then have the problem that in some cases they overlap nodes and mean the nodes can't be clicked on to expand/collapse the tree below that point. Look at the nodes two or three levels deeper than those labelled Male and Female - only somewhere between a third and a half of the nodes can be clicked on. (Note, nodes in the *bottom* layer aren't expandable/collapsible, as they have no children nodes.)

How am I best removing these labels, or at least stopping them preventing you from clicking on the nodes?

Things I've considered:

- Changing the draw order could presumably put the labels 'behind' the
  nodes - but I think this would involve substantial reworking of the
  code, and I don't know how
- Presumably it'd be possible to
  subsequently go through and remove nodes with the `nonselectable`
  class, but this doesn't feel the most efficient approach, and I've
  had some trouble trying to implement it
- I guess shifting the labels to
  somewhere outside the dimensions of the svg might work - though I'm
  not sure how I'd handle this with the transition, so that it isn't
  seen by users
- Setting a `font-size` of close to zero. I've tried
  tacking something like the code below onto my `nodeUpdate` code, but it seemed to cause problems with the transition

```
.attr("font-size", function(d) {
    if (minSpacing[d.depth]<requiredSpacing[d.depth]*2 || (d.data.position=='left' && Math.ceil(d.x/5)*5-radiuses[d.depth]-requiredSpacing[d.depth]<margin.left) || (d.data.position=='right' && Math.ceil(d.x/5)*5+radiuses[d.depth]+requiredSpacing[d.depth]>width)) {
        return '0.1em';
    }
})
```

Or there may be another, better way of solving this.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a `pointer-events: none;` to those labels:

```
.nonselectable {
    pointer-events: none;
    etc...
}
```

Actually, since I'm seeing that the labels are not clickable, you could set `pointer-events: none;` to **all** of them.

Here is the updated JSFidle: https://jsfiddle.net/e3j7ta4y/